# is there any way to do a select query with different where for two different condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do a query that use select to display reports on a table, the table contents that will be displayed is depends on transaction date and the user group that logged in, if the user group is a normal user, the user only can see reports that he/she only manage, if the user group is admin, then the user can see all reports.

here's the example of my unfinished query : (edited)

```
SELECT store_id, type, tx_date, status, amount1, amount2, total
FROM table1 t1 JOIN user_rights us ON t1.store_id = us.store_id
WHERE us.user_group IS NOT 'admin' AND us.uname = {logged in username} AND tx_date = {date inputed by user}
```

as you can see, this query is only displayed what the normal users can see. My problem is when the user that are logged in is an admin. The query can't display all of the data reported because the where is already filtered the data.

So i think the query for admin is only : (edited)

```
SELECT t1.store_id, type, tx_date, status, amount1, amount2, total
FROM table1 t1 JOIN user_rights us ON t1.store_id = us.store_id
WHERE tx_date = {date inputed by user}
```

Here's what user_rights table look like

```
|   rights_id   |   uname   |  user_group  |  store_id  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     r0001     |   a0001   |     admin    |     a1     |
|     r0002     |   u0001   |     user     |     a2     |
|     r0003     |   u0002   |     user     |     b1     |
|     r0004     |   u0002   |     user     |     b2     |
```

The example result that i want for admin(a0001) for date (14/4/20) is like :

```
|  store_id  |  type  |  tx_date  |  status  |  amount1  |  amount2  |  total  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     a1     |  groc  |  14/4/20  |   done   |    10000  |     -     |  10000  |
|     a2     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    30000  |    50000  |  80000  |
|     b1     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    40000  |    20000  |  60000  |
|     b2     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    30000  |    50000  |  80000  |
```

The example result that i want for user(u0001) for date (14/4/20) is like :

```
|  store_id  |  type  |  tx_date  |  status  |  amount1  |  amount2  |  total  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     a2     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    30000  |    50000  |  80000  |
```

The example result that i want for user(u0002) for date (14/4/20) is like :

```
|  store_id  |  type  |  tx_date  |  status  |  amount1  |  amount2  |  total  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     b1     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    40000  |    20000  |  60000  |
|     b2     |  supp  |  14/4/20  |   pend   |    30000  |    50000  |  80000  |
```

is there any possible way to only use select to solve this problem ?

edit : I make a mistake before , table1 contains store transaction data, i've added some details information from the example, i changed the user table into user_rights table, because i think my information is unclear, so i hope the information that i add will help you better understanding what my problem is. Sorry for making a lot of editing, because this is the first time i post here.

note : Because this only purpose for reporting, this should be completed in only select statement. Making new tables or other procedures is considered unecessary because this query only used for one report.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display columns from `table1` only, you could use `exists` for filtering with conditional logic:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where 
    t1.tx_date = ?
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from users u
        where 
            u.Name = ?
            and (us.user_group = 'admin' or u.id = t1.id)
    )
```

Where the question marks represent (respectively) the date inputed by the user and their name.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake in explaining my problem, i've edited the post again. so the thing that i want is the admin can see all the transactioni from all stores, but the normal user only can see the stores that they're only manage. In this case, some stores are managed by the admin too

Comment: @hansbakti: I think this query should do what you want. Did you try it? Otherwise, you migh want to furthermore improve your question by adding sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be completed in a single statement? Could you make the first call using the admin logic, store this in a temp table adding a column to the end that is populated using a Case statement. something along the lines of, if us.usergroup = admin then enter user id else if us.id = t1.id then enter user id.

You could then use a second select statement thats pulls all records from the temp table where the users id is in the new column of the temp table.

I hope I've interpreted your question correctly.

Comment: Because this only purpose for reporting, this should be completed in only select statement. Making new tables or other procedures is cconsidered unecessary because this only use for one report. but thanks for answering :D

Comment: Please comment on post for clarification instead of posting as answer.

Comment: @Digvijay : i've edited the post, thankyou for your reminder

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF-Statement to check if the user is an admin or not and trigger the respective query. Something like:

```
IF({SELECT TO THECK IF USER = 'admin'})
BEGIN
    SELECT id, type, time, status, amount1, amount2, total
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN user us ON t1.id = us.id
    WHERE tx_date = {date inputed by user}
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT id, type, tx_date, status, amount1, amount2, total
    FROM table1 t1 JOIN user us ON t1.id = us.id
    WHERE us.user_group IS NOT 'admin' AND us.uname = {logged in username} AND tx_date = {date inputed by user}
END
```

Comment: That would require PL/SQL and a stored function. I doubt that's what hans bakti wants

Comment: yeah, i know this solutions is exist, but i can't use stored procedure for this query

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `or`?

```
SELECT store_id, type, tx_date, status, amount1, amount2, total
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     user us
     ON t1.store_id = us.store_id
WHERE tx_date = {date inputed by user} AND
      ( (us.user_group IS NOT 'admin' AND us.uname = {logged in username}) OR
        (us.user_group = 'admin')
      );
```

Note that this assumes that the same columns are returned for both admins and non-admins.  If they return different columns, then you should ask a new question.

Comment: I've considered this, but the result will only display the transaction that managed by the user with user group admin, instead of that, the one that i want is the admin can see all the transaction from any user from any user group

Comment: @hansbakti . . . No.  An admin will be able to see any rows that match the date condition.

Comment: because i joined the table, so if i use this, if an admin that logged in, the first condition will failed, but the table will only display rows where the user_group is 'admin' because of the second condition